# MySQL Create view with stored procedure

Tags: mysql

Evening kind sirs/madames;

I'm attempting to create a stored procedure that updates a view in MySQL.  In a nutshell, when the trainingType database gets updated, the view trsReq (which is essentially a pivot table of employees by trainingType. Training records are stored in a view, trs) needs to get updated.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 5000;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('max(IF(type =',id,', data, "")) AS "',shortDesc,'",max(IF(type =',id,', trs.status, "")) AS "',shortDesc,'_status"')) into @sql FROM trainingType where required=1;
SET @sql = CONCAT('create view trsReq as SELECT fName, lName, empId, ', @sql, ' FROM trs left join employee on trs.empId=employee.id where employee.inactive=0 GROUP BY empId order by lName, fName limit 100');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Executing that set of commands results in this:

```
ERROR 1142 (42000): ANY command denied to user `'user'@'localhost'` for table 

    '/var/mysqltmp/#sql_285f_0'
```

Comment: I should note, this is on a hostgator hosting plan.  I don't have access to change any permissions.  I have granted all permissions that are available in cPanel to the appropriate database.

From "Show grants":
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*D5******'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `database\_time3`.* TO 'admin'@'localhost'

Comment: No. I ended up doing in in PHP...

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think after poking around more I found a solution that used an unprepared statement that worked -- wish I knew why the difference.